# How to set expire time when add a task to resque?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

I'm using Rails with Resque.

I know the command of `redis-cli` is:

```
expire key 100
```

But I don't know how to set the expire time when adding a task to resque, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the redis connection:

```
Resque.redis.expire "key", 100
```

The redis is defined in `redis-rb` gem